# Primary key duplicate in a table-valued parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, primary-key, table-valued-parameters

I am using following code to insert date by Table Valued Parameter in my SP.

```
INSERT INTO banking.receivedcash
            (receivedcashid,
             date,
             time)
SELECT (SELECT Isnull(Max(receivedcashid), 0) + 1
        FROM   banking.receivedcash),
       t.date,
       t.time
FROM   @TVPCash AS t
```

Actually it works when one record exists in my TVP but when it has more than one record it raises the following error :

> 'Violation of Primary key constraint 'PK_ReceivedCash''.  Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'Banking.ReceivedCash'.  The statement has been terminated.

Comment: There is a PRIMARY key on `Banking.ReceivedCash`, and you are violating it by inserting a row that has the exact same key in it. Solution: don't insert a row with the same key, or alter your key because it isn't a proper key.

Comment: @TT. actually I try to insert unique value by this code as you see 
(select  isnull(Max(ReceivedCashID),0)+1 from Banking.ReceivedCash)
but It doesnt work when there are more than one record to insert !!

Comment: Make `ReceivedCashID` an [IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) column instead.

Comment: @TT. requirement is to be only primary key without auto incerement

Comment: I'm always curious about these blanket design constraints that make no sense and just introduce complexity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is indeed flawed if there is more than one row in `@TVPCash`. The query to retrieve the maximum `ReceivedCashID` is a constant, which is then used for each row in `@TVPCash` to insert into `Banking.ReceivedCash`.

I strongly suggest finding alternatives rather than doing it this way. Multiple users might run this query and retrieve the same maximum. If you insist on keeping the query as it is, try running the following:

```
insert into banking.receivedcash(
    ReceivedCashID,
    Date,
    Time
)
select 
    (select  isnull(Max(ReceivedCashID),0) from Banking.ReceivedCash)+
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.Date,t.Time),
    t.Date,
    t.Time 
from 
    @TVPCash as t
```

This uses [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to count the row number in `@TVPCash` and adds this to the maximum `ReceivedCashID` of `Banking.ReceivedCash`.

Comment: This is a quality answer that 100% fulfills the askers requirements, The OP should keep in mind that if two seperate processes submit a dataset where `ReceivedCashId` could overlap, you'll again get a PK error. Identity solves this issue